# How to get customer email list who purchased anything?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database

I want to retrieve customers who purchase anything from all registered customers. I have use following to retrieve all registered customers.

```
$users = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('email');

      foreach ($users as $user)
      var_dump($user->getData());
```

How do I filter purchased customers from them? Need to export the list of customers who have ever made the purchase (not just registered ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /*only registered*/
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('notnull' => true));

/*all registered and not registered*/
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $order)
      var_dump($order->getCustomerEmail());
```

Comment: Great It works.

Answer (score 0):

Get register customer email:

```
$registerCustomerOrderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('notnull' => true));

foreach ($registerCustomerOrderCollection as $order){
      echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
}
```

you get all user email list who purchase anything.